# Custom UIView alert not appearing after successful Login

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to trigger a small, timed `UIView` popup after a user successfully logs in, however, I need it to appear on the screen after the `LoginController` is dismissed. Can anyone help in understanding where I am going wrong here? Perhaps it is necessary to trigger it from the `rootViewController` after the view is dismissed, but I don't know how to trigger it from the `LoginController`.

The `LoginController` dismisses properly, and the print statement is logging so I know the completion block is working properly, however the `UIView` is not staying on top of other views.

Should I create some sort of `extension` that allows me to trigger it from another class? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

LoginController()

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                // completion handler after successful login
                print("completion handler: logged in")
                self.showAlert()
                })
    }
```

Custom alert/popup functions

```
func showAlert()    {
    popupAlert = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 200))
    popupAlert?.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(popupAlert)

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(dismissAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func dismissAlert()   {
    if popupAlert != nil {
        popupAlert.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the root vc is the login 1 so your code inside completion doesn't trigger , so add it to window

```
extension UIViewController { 
    func showAlert() {
        let popupAlert = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 200))
        popupAlert.backgroundColor = .red
        let wind = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!
        wind.addSubview(popupAlert) 
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4.0, repeats: false) { (t) in
            t.invalidate() 
            popupAlert.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add popupAlert on app window instead of self.view

```
 func showAlert()    {
    popupAlert = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 200))
    popupAlert?.backgroundColor = .red
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    app.window?.addSubview(popupAlert)

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(dismissAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```